# Passing generic type to a generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, interface

I am trying to implement a totally generic CRUD API whereby any class type can be passed in and generically saved, updated etc by the context.

I have a repository that saves any model type like this:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class 
    {
        private Context _db = new Context();

        public T Add(T newItem) 
        {
            var result = _db.Set<T>().Add((T)newItem);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

This inherits from a generic interface that implements all the "add" method:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T Add(T newItem);
}
```

I am struggling to understand why I can't pass a generic type into a new instance of the repository interface? I would ideally like something like:

```
var data = new Data(){
    Id = 1
};

IRepository<data.GetType()> repo = new Repository<data.GetType()>();
```

Thereby allowing me to pass any type into the method and generating the correct interface off the back of this.

It allows me to pass in a concrete type but that sort of defeats the object of making it generic.

Any ideas around this or explanations of why it's not possible will be greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: With the code given at the end im not following why you cant just pass in `Data` as the generic type. You already know what it is, its a `Data` - it cant possibly be a `Foo` or a `Bar`. Generics are for compile-time type safety, not run-time type safety. If you don't know the type until run-time, then generics is (probably) the wrong solution for you

Comment: I understand that, Data was an example type that may get passed. The idea behind it is to instantiate the interface with a type got at runtime. If this is the wrong solution can you tell me why or offer some further explanation?

Comment: Most likely the problem is over-simplified for this question. Most likely he's trying to write a transition from a non-generic world (where you have `object`) to a generic world (where you need the compile-time type of the object, other than `object`).

Comment: Since you're resorting to reflection, you have to do more with reflection, but you're not going to end up with a variable that is `IRepository<T>`, you're going to end up with a variable that isn't generic, be it a non-generic `IRepository`, or simply `object`.

Comment: As @Jamiec said, generics are for **compile-time** type safety. Since you're trying to do the final step of generics at **runtime**, you're going to have problems.

Comment: Do you have a non-generic interface you could use, `IRepository`, so that this code would work: `IRepository repo = new Repository<data.GetType()>();` ? (if we can fix the `<data.GetType()>` part that is)

Comment: That's the next step if I can't find a solution this way. I'm trying to avoid having to write a lot of different interfaces that are specific to each type. The other alternative is to have a switch case on the type and new up the interface based on whatever the type is.

Comment: We can construct an object of the right class via reflection, but you won't get a value out where you know the `<T>` part, it simply cannot be done. You need to have a non-generic type you can store this into.

Comment: Here's how to construct the repository: `object repo = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(data.GetType()));`. You cannot, however, get a `<T>` type at the start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to implement a *generic* repository with a generic parameter on the `IRepository` itself doesn't make sense because the term *generic* (in this case) does not refer to CLR generics but to the nature of the repository, which is the ability to work with different types of entities using the same repository instance, in contrast to repository-per-type approach (like `ProductsRepository` for example).

Placing the generic parameter on the methods can easily solve the problem:

```
public interface IRepository
{
     T GetById<T>(object id);
     IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria);
     T Add<T>(T data);
}
```

Possible implementation using EntityFramework would be:

```
public class EntityFrameworkRepository : IRepository
{
    public T GetById<T>(object id)
    {
        return this.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
    {
        return this.Set<T>().Where(criteria);
    }

    public T Add<T>(T data)
    {
        this.Set<T>().Add(data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome dude, this is the best solution and fixed the issue. Cheers.

Comment: I omitted the constraint `where T : class` for brevity. Entity Framework won't let you use `Set<T>` without it. I assume you realized that.

Answer (score 1):

You've hit upon a *constraint* of generics (I was going to use the word "limitation", but that's wrong - it's not a limitation, quite the opposite).

Generics provide you type safety at compile-time, it allows cleaner code, but you must know the type you're working with at compile-time. If you do not know the type until run time, as it seems you don't then generics is almost certainly the wrong solution.

Library developers know this, they know you often can not or do not want to specify the type, so often they provide a non-generic equivalent. The non-generic equivalent takes a `Type` as a traditional parameter rather than a generic parameter.

For example, I think you're using the `DbSet<T>` in EntityFramework, but EntityFramework also provides a non generic `DbSet`.

So this line in your code:

```
var result = _db.Set<T>().Add((T)newItem);
```

Could be written as

```
var result = _db.Set(newItem.GetType()).Add(newItem);
```

Expanding this out, you could define a non-generic `IRepository`:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    object Add(object newItem);
}
```

And implement it as

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private Context _db = new Context();
    private Type entityType;
    public Repository (Type entityType)
    {
        this.entityType= entityType;
    }

    public object Add(object newItem) 
    {
        var result = _db.Set(entityType).Add(newItem);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return result;
    }
}
```

It will work, but you've lost all type safety, making the response from your `Add` method near-on useless.

All in all, once you've followed this rabbit hole I suspect you'll return to the generic solution - it's light-years ahead of the non-generic solution (Thats why generics were added!)